# Android remove string from start to perticular character

Tags: android, string

I want to remove `string` from `starting index` to particular special character inside string.

Just for example, i have this kind of `string` `1521712285.83746b9`, and i want to remove from `'1' to '.'` and then store after string.

If any idea about that please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want only second part

```
String original="1521712285.83746b9,";
String lastpart=original.split(".")[1];
```

if you want append first part at the end then

```
 String modified=original.split(".")[1]+original.split(".")[0]+".";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following

```
String str[] = yourStr.split(".");
String finalString = str[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring method of string and you will get your desired results.
Please visit here for detail information: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/string-java-basics/substring-java-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (null != str && str.length() > 0 )
{
    int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (endIndex != -1)  
    {
        String newstr = str.substring(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.